# EF Core One-To-One Bi-Directional Self-Referencing Table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, one-to-one, self-reference, bidirectional

I got some problems with EF Core.

I'm getting this error:

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to save changes because a circular dependency was detected in the data to be saved

Here is my model:

```cs
public class Transaction
{
    public int TransactionId { get; set; }

    public int? MutualTransactionId { get; set; }
    public virtual Transaction MutualTransaction { get; set; }

    public long Debit { get; set; }
    public long Credit { get; set; }
}
```

And here is my `OnModelCreating` configuration:

```cs
public class Repository : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Transaction>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(x => x.TransactionId);

            entity.HasOne(x => x.MutualTransaction)
                .WithOne()
                .HasForeignKey<Transaction>(x => x.MutualTransactionId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_Transactions_Mutuals");
        });
    }
}
```

The problem occurs when I want to seed a range of data into the database.

The error itself is not important. I just want to know how to make an one-to-one bi-directional self-referencing table using EF Core.

Each row refers to another row from the same table and the referred to row also refers back to this row using the same property in the model class.

Comment: You **MUST NOT** Capitalize Each And Every Single Word In Your English!

Comment: You can only insert a directed acyclic graph in one call to save changes. Either [add, save, update, save], or maybe write a trigger to fixup the first record when the second one is inserted.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this may works :

```
 public class Transaction
    {
        public int TransactionId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("MutualTransaction"), Column(Order = 0)]
        public int? MutualTransactionId { get; set; }
        
    
        public long Debit { get; set; }
        public long Credit { get; set; }
        public virtual Transaction MutualTransaction { get; set; }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are referring to as a "One to One" relationship isn't actually what a "One to One" relationship is, it is a self-referencing "Many to One" relationship.

You don't need explicit mapping for this relationship, a simple attribute mapping will work just fine, but if you want explicit mapping /w modelBuilder:

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<Transaction>(entity =>
    {
        entity.HasKey(x => x.TransactionId);

        entity.HasOne(x => x.MutualTransaction)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.MutualTransactionId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction)
            .HasConstraintName("FK_Transactions_Mutuals");
    });
```

One to One relationships are between two different tables that typically share the same PK. For example if a Transaction has some big binary column that you don't typically need and don't want the overhead of loading when retrieving a transaction.

This is a typical self-referencing parent style many-to-1 relationship. If you want to ensure that an entity only is ever referenced by one other entity (1 child) and that child can only have that 1 parent then you either have to enforce that by application logic, or adopt a joining many-to-many table with unique constraints added on each of the keys making up the composite PK.

Update: If you want MutualTransaction to reference co-dependents, then this is allowed, but not enforced. For example if I want Transaction A and B to be co-dependent, where A's Mutual is B and B's is A, then you can accomplish this with the above mapping and a Many-to-One, but it is an implied rule that has to be enforced by the application (not the database) so you have to rely on code, and possibly database script health checks to regulate it's enforcement. The catch is that it requires 2 explicit saves:

```
var transactionA = new Transaction{ Name = "A" };
var transactionB = new Transaction{ Name = "B", MutualTransaction = transactionA };
context.Transactions.Add(transactionA);
context.Transactions.Add(transactionB);
context.SaveChanges();
transactionA.MutualTransaction = transactionB;
context.SaveChanges();
```

Now you can load either entity and access the reference to the mutual partner.

I.e.

```
var test = context.Transactions
    .Include(x => x.MutualTransaction)
    .Single(x => x.Name == "A");
// or
var test2 = context.Transactions
    .Include(x => x.MutualTransaction)
    .Single(x => x.Name == "B");
```

It'd be nice if this worked:

```
var transactionA = new Transaction{ Name = "A" };
var transactionB = new Transaction{ Name = "B", MutualTransaction = transactionA };
transactionA.MutualTransaction = transactionB;
context.Transactions.Add(transactionA);
context.Transactions.Add(transactionB);
context.SaveChanges();
```

but that results in the circular reference issue within EF.

Comment: But then how can I access parent from child or vice versa? I mean I can get Mutual Transacrion by simply calling for example ```var transaction2 = transaction1.MutualTransaction``` but can it be accessed backward from the same property? I mean is this true : ```transaction2.MutualTransaction.TransactionId == transaction1.TransactionId```

Comment: I had to try it out when I got back to my test projects before I replied, but it looks like it is possible to use that mutual transaction for your co-dependent references. I've updated my answer above to outline how that's done and the caveats of that approach.